# ETag usage and resources modification

Tags: rest, concurrency, etag

## Context

I have 2 resources -it's an example, don't pay attention to the relevance of it- which are linked together:

- `/customers/{id}` that provide information about the age, sexe, firstName, etc... about a customer.
- `/customers/{id}/age` that corresponds to the age attribute of the customer. For performance issue, this resource exists. To be compliant with the HATEOAS constraint, a link is provided from the `/customers/{id}` resource.

## Problem

An application can perform an update  with **PUT** either on the `/customers/{id}` or `/customers/{id}/age` resource.

As the age attribute is related to both resources, an update of the age can be perform in 2 different ways leading to conflict.
So ETag seems to be the silver bullet to solve my problem ;-)!

## Questions

Two questions underlying to this example and more general:

- Does an update of a resource can leads to modify the ETag of this resource (obvious) **and** to an other resource ?
  In my example, an update of the resource `/customers/{id}/age` modify the etag for both resource. This one and `/customers/{id}`.
- Could the modification of the ETag be conditional ? 
  I mean, if an application modify only the firstName when updating the `/customers/{id}` resource and not the age, i don't want to update the ETag of the `/customers/{id}/age` resource.

An even more general question: Is there some good practices about using ETag header or I can do whatever i want ?

Comment: What conflict? The last `PUT` wins.

Comment: If you have 2 applications updating a same field, age here, yes there is a conflict. My question is not about conflict resolution, but about updating the ETag header (on the server side) which is one of the way to handle conflict. Your comment is another one, but it's offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of situation arises quite often. It often natural to view resources as a hierachy (i.e a tree) where 'parent' items depend on their children, whereas the children not necessarily depend on their parents. When a leaf item is update, i.e. the ETag changes, that effect ripples up all the way to the root.

One example is CardDAV, where an address book has a "ctag" that is dependent on the ETags of of all vCard entries in the collection. In this case, the ctag is not explicilty expressed as an ETag, but it could very well have been.

Comment: That's a nice answer. You totally got the idea of dependencies between parent and children items. Thanks.